# Allow internet access only through vpn server

Tags: vpn, proxy, remote-connection

I want our domain clients to be able to access internet only while connected to our VPN server, so they are safe on all foreign Wi-Fi.

How can I accomplish this? Windows 10 proxy?

Comment: Find a similar requirement, perhaps it can help you. https://serverfault.com/questions/289179/is-it-possible-to-force-pptp-vpn-tunnel-as-the-only-internet-connection-on-a-win

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest is to use a firewall rule which you may push to the users.

A simple and easy trick is to designate the general network as Public and the VPN
as Work/Private, then block all traffic on Public networks.

For more information see :

- [How to Configure Firewall in Such a Way That When VPN Disconnects, All Browsing Stops (Windows7)](https://support.purevpn.com/windows7-firewall)
- [How to Block Internet Access with Group Policy (GPO)](https://www.gypthecat.com/how-to-block-internet-access-with-group-policy)